# Is there a way to delay page redirect with javascript in Gravity Forms confirmation settings?

Tags: javascript, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to delay URL redirect so that values on a spreadsheet can be done calculating before the redirect occurs.  The redirect takes the form submitter to a page that shows updated information as a results of the form response.

Here is the script I am trying to include in the Text Editor of the confimation settings page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
window.location = 'URL Here';
3500); // 3.5 seconds
</script>
```

The note from Gravity Forms is:

> The text you have entered is not valid. For security reasons, some characters are not allowed. Fix it

When I click "Fix it", the script tags are removed by Gravity Forms, leaving me with this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = 'https://intranet.onyxcollection.com/shop-management/home/lav-accessory-casting/';
    }, 3500); // 3.5 seconds
```

Is there a different approach to what I am trying to achieve, aside from modifying the PHP file which I have no access to since I am not the site administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including Javascript in a Gravity Forms confirmation is still possible.  The issue I was experiencing was due to limitations imposed by Gravity Forms.

Apparently, only SuperAdmins can add Javascript to the Gravity Forms confirmations.  Once our team received this answer from the folks at Gravity Forms, my SuperAdmin added the Javascript snippet I gave him and everything now performs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script like the one below in a code snippet plugin if you don't have access to the files.

You would still use your text confirmation, but the code will handle the rest.

**Important, the form embed must have ajax enabled for this to work.**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, formId){
            if(formId == 1)// change 1 with your forms ID 
            {
               function Redirect() {
               window.location = "https://google.com/";//put redirect URL here
               }
               setTimeout(function() {
               Redirect();
               }, 2000);// 2 seconds
      }
   });
})
```

Filter doc reference here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_loaded

These are a couple of code snippet plugins:

- [https://codebox.com](https://wpcodebox.com/?ref=155)
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/
- [https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-custom-javascript/](https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-custom-javascript/?ref=158)

There are two other solutions in this doc, ignore #2 it's the solution you've already tried:
https://gravityranger.com/display-text-confirmation-before-redirecting-gravity-forms/

Comment: I can't install plugins either due to my restricted Admin Settings (I only manage a subsite of the main company site), which is why adding javascript seemed like the best option for me.  Unfortunate that Gravity Forms appeared to have disabled this functionality.  If, after talking with Site Administrator, installing the plugin is an option, I will test this script.

Comment: @codedabbler, that original script you posted still works for me. Are you checking the box to disable auto-formatting: https://docs.wprescue.me/Qwuwgn4N

Comment: Yes, and I get the error message as shown above.